# Firebase read rules based on data key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have my data in the following structure:

```
writings: {
    'xxx-key-xxx': {
        'user-id': 'xxxxx',
        'title': 'title',
        'content': 'content'
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to allow read access to user only to his documents:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "writings": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && (root.child('writings').child('user-id').val() === auth.uid)",
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. I suspect I'm not fitering the child `user-id` key correctly. Any idea?

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you show the code that reads that you don't want to work? Or vice versa: the code that can't read, that you want to be able?

Comment: I'm simulating in the firebase console and it gets denied. I have data stored with `uid` set as the UID used in the simulator but it fails to read.

Comment: The path simulated is for `/writings/`. I want to fetch all writings that the user has.

Comment: How do you plan to query this location (`/writings`)? Query ordered by child and equal to the user id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `auth.uid` to the value of the path `/writings/user-id`, which is missing a key `xxx-key-xxx`, so this will always be false since data at this path does not exist. You could alter your rules to get the key of a child, however, this would limit your `.read` permission to reading individual `writings` children e.g.

```
{
  "writings": {
    "$wid": {
      ".read": "auth !== null && root.child('writings/$wid/user-id').val() === auth.uid"
```

*or equivalently*

```
      ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('user-id').val() === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Using these rules, you will see `Permission Denied` when trying to read `/writings` - you must read the documents individually and so you must know the key of each document. Now we know all we need are the keys of each document, we need to find a way of retrieving them.

A common way of representing relationships like this is by fanning out the data. We have the `uid` of the user and we want the keys of the documents they own. If you were to maintain another root node that stored the keys of each user's documents only accessible by them, then you could refer to that location to retrieve the user's documents.

```
{
  "user-writings": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
      "$wid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    ...
  },
  "writings": {
    "$wid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('user-id').val()",
      ".write": "auth.uid === newData.child('user-id').val()"
    }
  }
}
```

These rules ensure user's can only view their own documents by virtue of only having access to their document's keys in `user-writings/$uid`. When a user creates a writing, they would also need to write to `user-writings/$uid/$wid` setting the value to `true`.

Now to retrieve the documents that belong to a user, you would query the location `user-writings/$uid` with the user's uid to retrieve the keys and then have to get the data of each `writings/$wid` the user owns. It may be suitable for you to ditch `writings` altogether and store each user's documents at their corresponding location in the database (`user-writings/$uid`).